# Pycharm Flask CSS not changing anything but getting a 200 status

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I'm working on a project with flask and python in pycharm. My css will not do anything, even really basic things. When I go to the network tab and refresh, I get a 200 message for the CSS file, so I know my link works. Problem is, nothing changes. Also whatever port I'm running on, if I change and save the CSS and open it through dev tools, it doesn't update unless I change to a new port. Any ideas why no CSS is running but I get a 200? Or why I have to change ports to update CSS? Thanks!

Comment: Mind showing us the code where you reference the css file in your HTML template, along with any other necessary code for helping us understand your problem?

Comment: Could you try importing the `css` file with the help of `link` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers cache CSS properties usually. Try hard reloading when you change something. For chrome, you can use `ctrl`+`shift`+`R`.

Answer (score 0):

You could either hard reload the browser tab after clearing the cache or try opening the URL in incognito mode. If it works in incognito mode, then its a caching issue.